How to convert time in decimals to time format
I have a data set with a variable for hours in a decimal format (see example df).
I need to convert it to time format (see example df2)
I am trying with lubridate but it gives me wrong values. Do you know how could I easily do it?
Thank you so much in advance
df <- as.data.frame(c(9.5, 9.75, 9, 9.25))
df2 <- as.data.frame(c("9:30", "9:45", "9" , "9:15"))


Do you want your values in df2 to be (Date)Times or characters?

lubritate works with moments in time (dates or date/hours), timespans (durations or periods) and intervals (two associated moments in time). To work with "clock time" only, you need lubridate's brother hms.
Here's the catch: both packages have a hms function.  lubridate::hms parses time as period (timespan) and this is not what you want.  You're looking for hms::hms, which parses "clock time".
That said, it's really simple. Try this:
library(tidyverse)

# Toy data
df_in <- tibble(time = c(9.5, 9.75, 9, 9.25))

# Use `hms::hms`
df_out <- mutate(df_in, hms_time = hms::hms(hour = time))

The output:
> df_out
# A tibble: 4 × 2
   time hms_time
  <dbl> <time>  
1  9.5  09:30   
2  9.75 09:45   
3  9    09:00   
4  9.25 09:15  

That's it. If you have time, read the documentation here.
Created on 2024-05-17 with reprex v2.1.0

Appropriate "POSIXt" format has a date included, you could use Sys.Date().
> x <- c(9.5, 9.75, 9, 9.25)
> as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) + x*60
[1] "2024-05-17 00:09:30 UTC" "2024-05-17 00:09:45 UTC" "2024-05-17 00:09:00 UTC" "2024-05-17 00:09:15 UTC"


The answer using hms seems simplest but if you would like a base R solution that does not use explicit arithmetic or string manipulation then convert to "difftime" class using "hours" as the units and then convert that to numeric seconds using as.numeric and then POSIXct which we can then format.  If dplyr is ok then replace transform with mutate.
df <- data.frame(x = c(9.5, 9.75, 9, 9.25))

df |>
  transform(y = as.difftime(x, units = "hours") |>
    as.numeric(units = "secs") |>
    as.POSIXct(tz = "GMT") |>
    format("%H:%M")
  )

giving
     x     y
1 9.50 09:30
2 9.75 09:45
3 9.00 09:00
4 9.25 09:15


Here is solution using tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x = c(9.5, 9.75, 9, 9.25))

df %>% 
  mutate(
    y = paste0(floor(x), ":", str_pad((x %% 1) * 60, 2, "right", "0"))
  )

     x    y
1 9.50 9:30
2 9.75 9:45
3 9.00 9:00
4 9.25 9:15


Using strptime
mutate(df, xt=format(strptime(
      paste(floor(x), (x - floor(x))*60, sep=":"), 
      format="%H:%M"), format="%H:%M"))

     x    xt
1 9.50 09:30
2 9.75 09:45
3 9.00 09:00
4 9.25 09:15


df <- data.frame(x = c(9.5, 9.75, 9, 9.25))


dec_to_hour <- function(x, hide_trailing_zero = FALSE) {
  hour <- floor(x)
  minu <- (x %% 1 * 60)
  outp <- sprintf("%d:%02d", hour, minu)
  if (hide_trailing_zero) sub(":00$", "", outp) else outp 
}


dec_to_hour(x)
# [1] "9:30" "9:45" "9:00" "9:15"
dec_to_hour(x, TRUE)
# [1] "9:30" "9:45" "9"    "9:15"

Where
x <- c(9.5, 9.75, 9, 9.25)

